# SQL Report Builder: MIN date not pulling true MIN, somehow using a WHERE clause equivalent

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder 3.0, there's a report that I am rebuilding (this 'old' report is being fed from old DB, I am rebuilding report using data from new DB). The old report appears to somehow be using a WHERE clause equivalent, but I can't figure out how it's working. Here's the basic structure...At the bottom is the tablix that lists multiple rows (`[DueDt1]`) and the MIN function above is pulling the MIN date, but it is pulling the MIN date only for the rows where the `[Total Still Due]` is > 0.

[image]

---

*(nothing more than a MIN, if anyone was curious)*
[image]

---

So to see the actual results, this first shot here shows the supposed "MIN" date of 7/27/2019:

[image]

However, the real MIN date is actually 6/21/2019. It's clearly only fetching the MIN date as it pertains to some kind of WHERE clause equivalent (I say equivalent because I know there's no WHERE option in SQL Report Builder) that's filtering to only look at rows with the `[Total Still Due]` being > 0.

[image]

[image]

Here's the thing: this is what I want my new report to do, but when I attempt to use a MIN date function, it pulls the "real" MIN date. So how is this old report effectively using a WHERE equivalent? There is only one dataset that the old report is using, and only one dataset that my new report is using. Somehow, the old report has some kind of WHERE clause equivalent and I have no idea where or what it is. Any ideas as to how this is occurring?

Comment: Try using `MAX()`

Comment: I changed it to MAX and it did pull the actual MAX value, but that's what I'd expect it  to do. Sorry, what's the context behind this experiment?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question at first... Let me try again. Does the report have any groupings? You might want to check the filtering within the group and the row. Also might want to check any row visibility expressions if there are any.

Comment: Great ideas. I checked the groups, and there is one group that is grouping on customer: that's to allow for the SUM(Total_Amt) to function as intended, it seems. No filtering on that group, and no row visibility expressions.

Comment: I figured it out. There was a filter on the tablix itself. I realize now what it was doing (I'm not well-versed with the old DB). It was filtering out the extraneous rows via a Status column, which is what allowed the MIN to capture the correct value. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: If you go to the Fields tab in the Data Set properties, is DueDt1 a calculated field or does it come straight from the query?